Cloth simulation keeps merging with itself or other cloth and start flying away
I am creating a simple bowl of noodles. My constant problem is that the noodles keeps getting sucked in by itself or when i have a more than one noodle it gets sucked into that. I have increase the collision distance and self collision But i really have no idea how to fix it.
I do apologies for my terrible english.

Hello please share your file (make it as simple as possible)

Have you checked the normals? If they are inverted, this effect can occur.
